# How to make sub menu items of sub menu

Tags: css, menu, nav

I want to make 2nd or 3rd level menu items of this menu. I try on last menu i.e contact but first sub menu level work well but when i try to make 2nd or 3rd level sub menu it does'nt work plx plx some body help me for this. Thnx in advance.

```css
.nav {
    /*background-color:#52edc7;*/
 background-color:transparent;
    width:auto;
    }
 
.nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
 
.nav ul li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    }
 
.nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 30px 10px 30px;
    color:#52b4ed;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s; /* Safari */
    }  
     
.nav ul li:hover a {   
    color:#52b4ed;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#242740;
    transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s; /* Safari */
 -moz-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
 -0-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
    }
 .nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    }  
     
.nav ul li:hover ul {
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
}  
 
.nav ul li ul
{
    position:relative;      
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
       -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
            box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.nav ul li ul:before, .nav ul li ul:after
{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top:50%;
    bottom:0;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
    border-radius:100px / 10px;
 
}
 
.nav ul li ul li {
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    float:none;
 color:#000; 
 
 }
 
.nav ul li ul li:hover a { 
    color:#d73914;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s; /* Safari */
    }
 
.nav ul li ul li {}
 
.nav ul li ul li a {
    padding:5px 15px 5px 15px;
    text-align:left;
 
    }
 
.nav ul li ul li a i {
    min-width:20px;
    padding-right:10px;
 
    }
 .nav li > a:after { content: ' »'; }
 
   
.nav > li > a:after {content: ' »'; }
 
  
.nav li > a:only-child:after {content: ''; }
.nav ul .active {
    color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-2x"></i><Br/>Home</a></li> <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-male fa-2x"></i><Br/>About</a>
     <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>Company</a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-1x"></i>Team</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    
   
     
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i><Br/>Contact Us</a>
   <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>USA</a>
   <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>LA</a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-1x"></i>NY</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-1x"></i>Other</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: Currently it show only 1st sub menu like it showing contact us sub menus USA and Other but it overlap USA sub menus i.e LA or NY. In short it shows only 1st sub menu but 2nd sub menu not show correctly. My desired result is USA sub menus LA or NY

Comment: please help me for sub sub menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want?

```css
.nav * {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  list-style:none;
  position: relative;  width:auto;

}
.nav ul li:hover{
    color:#52b4ed;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#242740;
    transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s; /* Safari */
 -moz-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
 -0-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
  display: block;
    
}
.nav a {
    display:block;
    color:#52b4ed;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 30px 10px 30px;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s; /* Safari */
}

.nav li a:after { content: ' »'; }

.firstlevel ul {
  position: absolute;
}
/*first level*/
.firstlevel > li > ul {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width:200px
}

/*other levels*/
.firstlevel > li > ul > li ul {
  left: 100;
  top: 0%;
  width:100%;
}
/*hide and show on hover*/
.firstlevel li > ul li {
  display: none;
}
.firstlevel li:hover > ul > li {color:#52b4ed;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#242740;
    transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s; /* Safari */
 -moz-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
 -0-transition: color 0.5s, background 0.5s;
  display: block;
}
.firstlevel li> ul > li:hover{
    background-color:#fff;
}
.firstlevel li> ul > li:hover a{
    color:#d73914;
}
.firstlevel li> ul li:hover>ul li{background-color:#fff}
.firstlevel li> ul li:hover>ul li a{color:#d73914;}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="firstlevel">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-2x"></i><Br/>Home</a></li> <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-male fa-2x"></i><Br/>About</a>
     <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>Company</a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-1x"></i>Team</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    
   
     
      <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i><Br/>Contact Us</a>
   <ul>
               <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>USA</a>
                   <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>LA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-1x"></i>NY</a></li></ul>
   <ul>
                
        </ul>
     </li>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-1x"></i>Other</a>
                <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>LA</a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-1x"></i>NY</a></li>
        </ul>
                </li>
        </ul></li>
    </ul>
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/188w9y8f/2/)

Comment: thnks for your help i'm very happy

Answer (score 1):

I haven't put in all your styling but i got your sub menus working. Wasn't sure where the 'Other' was supposed to go?

```css
nav {
  margin-top: 15px
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
nav ul a {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}
nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

nav ul li:hover {
  color: #52b4ed;
  background-color: #242740;
}
nav ul ul a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px 15px
}
nav ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 92px;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 10em;
}
.nav a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #ffb732;
  font-weight: 900
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ffc55a;
  color: #33b3a6;
  font-weight: 900
}
.nav li {
  position: relative;
}
.nav > li {
  float: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #6bf4e5;
}
.nav > li > .parent {
  background-image: url(../images/downArrow.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
.nav > li > a {
  display: block
}
.nav li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
.nav > li.hover > ul {
  left: 0;
}
.nav li:hover ul {
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
}
.nav li ul a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #c1f5ef;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top: 1px solid #66e6d9;
  overflow-y: none;
  font-weight: 560;
}
.nav li ul li ul a {
  background-color: #e0faf7;
  z-index: 200;
  border-top: 1px solid #707070;
  overflow-y: none;
}
li.parent,
ul.parent {
  -webkit-padding-start: 0 !important;
  -moz-padding-start: 0 !important;
  color: #c1f5ef;
}
ul.parent {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
  <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">USA &nbsp; &nbsp; >></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">NY</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">LA</a></li>
              
            </ul>
          </li>
        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
          
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  

</nav>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/prn2dbt1/2/)

Comment: thnks for your help too, i really appreciate your effort